# Persistent OAuth sessions for multiple command-line apps?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm developing a RESTful API for a web service that uses OAuth2 for authentication. Our third-party developer customers are interested in creating dozens of small command-line tools to work with the data. However, it would be cumbersome for them to have to log in each time they run a command.

What I am envisioning is something very much like "npm login" or "git login" - a utility which creates a persistent session on the command line. I imagine this would store the user's OAuth credentials in a private config file. The various third-party tools would call a Python library function (which we would also provide) that reads the file and verifies it with the service, returning them a token they can use on subsequent HTTP calls.

However, we would like each tool to have its own client id, so that we can distinguish one tool from another for metrics and reporting purposes. So I want to avoid a situation where the client id is fixed at the point of login.

Unfortunately, I am relatively new to OAuth and am not sure where to begin. Any advice or starting points would be helpful.

Comment: Oauth is for authorisation, not authentication.  Each until can have its own client id.  Rather than storing credentials, you should store the refresh token (in addition to the access token).

Comment: Can the refresh token be used to get a new access token using a different client id than the client id that was originally used to acquire the refresh token?

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches depending on your exact requirement. These are defined by OAuth 2.0 ([RFC6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)).

If you only require to identify the script type (ex:- Delete script, Data access script or whatever the purpose) and do not worry about end user, you can use **[Client Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4)**.

In this grant type, you define client id and client secret per script and obtain tokens per script using those credentials. This can be done as the first step in your script. You only require to handle token request and response.

If you need to identify the end user, then you should use **[Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3)**. This is similar to client credential grant but instead of client credentials, end user share their credentials with your script. Then your script call token endpoint to obtain tokens.

Both approaches does not involve a login screen from authorisation server. Thus they can be used by scripts (suitable for scripts). Choice is yours depending on the exact requirements.

Comment: I do need to know the user's identity, because we store the version history of each mutation and this includes who made the change. However, wouldn't the password approach require the user to log in separately for each command-line tool? That would be cumbersome if the number of tools was large.

Comment: well if you need user identity, then best choice is resource owner password credential grant. There won't be a login as in a login dialog. But your script will somehow require user credentials. How to pass that between many scripts is doubtful but I don't see any other approach for your situation. You will be lucky if all scripts can share same log in by running one script after another.